# Como extraer datos de un JSON retornado por PHP en AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Disculpen la molestia, solo quería saber si alguno me pudiera ayudar a resolver un problema.

Estoy realizando una pagina con HTML5, CSS, JS Y PHP, en la cual le paso valores con AJAX a PHP para que me los guarde en mi base de datos y, después, me retorne ciertos valores. Dichos valores los retorno en formato JSON, los cuales en el console se ven asi:

```html
{"Usuario":[{"ID_USUARIO":"1","0":"1"}],"Orden":"115","Factura":"85","FechaFactura":"2022-10-24 20:10:15","CosteEnvio":"25"}
```

Lo que quiero es tomar esos valores en AJAX ya que los quiero enviar a otro PHP para tratar con ellos, pero no se como realizar dicha accion. Probe lo siguiente:

```js
var retornado = JSON.stringify(response);

          var ID_Usuario = retornado.ID_Usuario;
          var ID_Orden = retornado.Orden;
          var ID_Factura = retornado.Factura;
          var FechaFactura = retornado.FechaFactura;
          var CosteEnvio = retornado.CosteEnvio;
```

Y en mi data coloco los datos asi:

```js
              data:{
              Usuario: ID_Usuario,
              Factura: ID_Factura,
              Orden: ID_Orden,
              Fecha: FechaFactura,
              CosteEnvio: CosteEnvio
}
```

Pero del lado de PHP, en donde recibo los valores, me da el siguiente error:

```html
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Usuario in <b>C:\laragon\www\DATABASE_PROJECT\generarFactura.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Factura in <b>C:\laragon\www\DATABASE_PROJECT\generarFactura.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Orden in <b>C:\laragon\www\DATABASE_PROJECT\generarFactura.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Fecha in <b>C:\laragon\www\DATABASE_PROJECT\generarFactura.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: CosteEnvio in <b>C:\laragon\www\DATABASE_PROJECT\generarFactura.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Usuario in <b>C:\laragon\www\DATABASE_PROJECT\generarFactura.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Feliz día

CODIGO JS:

```js
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "guardar.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        email: correo,
        dir: direccion,
        pago: value,
        dinero: monto,
        Tabla: TableData
      },
      success: function (response) {

        console.log(response);
        
        

        $('#crearFactura').on("click", function (event) {

          var retornado = JSON.stringify(response);

          var ID_Usuario = retornado.ID_Usuario;
          var ID_Orden = retornado.Orden;
          var ID_Factura = retornado.Factura;
          var FechaFactura = retornado.FechaFactura;
          var CosteEnvio = retornado.CosteEnvio;

          $.ajax({
            // la URL para la petición
            url: 'generarFactura.php',

            // la información a enviar
            // (también es posible utilizar una cadena de datos)
            data: {

              Email: correo,
              Direccion: direccion,
              MetodoPago: value,
              SubtotalFactura: monto,
              Usuario: ID_Usuario,
              Factura: ID_Factura,
              Orden: ID_Orden,
              Fecha: FechaFactura,
              CosteEnvio: CosteEnvio

            },

            // especifica si será una petición POST o GET
            type: 'POST',

            // el tipo de información que se espera de respuesta
            //dataType: 'json',

            success: function (json) {
              console.log(json);
            }
          });

        });




      }

    });
```

CODIGO DE PHP QUE ENVIA LOS DATOS:

```html
                        $datos = array();
                        $datos["Usuario"] = $ID_Usuario;
                        $datos["Orden"] = $ID_Orden;
                        $datos["Factura"] = $ID_Factura;
                        $datos["FechaFactura"] = $Fecha_Factura;
                        $datos["CosteEnvio"] = $CosteEnvio;

                        echo json_encode($datos);
```

CODIGO DE PHP QUE LOS RECIBE:

```
<?php

    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

    require_once('plantillas/plantillas/index2.php');

   // require_once('producto.php');

    IF($_POST){

    require_once('DatosFactura.php');

    $css = file_get_contents('plantillas/plantillas/style.css');

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([



    ]);

    $platilla = getPlantilla($Nombre_Usuario, $Direccion_Usuario, $Email_Usuario, $Factura, $Fecha, $Orden, $Nombre_Metodo, $SubtotalFactura, $CosteEnvio, $productos);

        $mpdf->writeHTML($css, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
    $mpdf->writeHTML($platilla, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
 
    $mpdf->Output();

    }

?>
```

El primer AJAX esta asociado a este modal. En este lo que hago es que, cuando presiona el boton, me envia datos mediante AJAX a un PHP para guardar los datos en la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se presiona el boton y "realiza" el pago, se abre el siguiente modular (por eso hay un evento click dentro del success del AJAX):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este lo que se busca es tomar los datos que returna el anterior PHP a AJAX (tales como ID del cliente, ID de la orden, Fecha, etc) para poder generar una factura al presionar el boton (son los datos que envia el segundo AJAX).

CODIGO PARA LA FACTURA:

```html
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');


    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

    require_once('plantillas/plantillas/index2.php');

    IF($_POST){

    $css = file_get_contents('plantillas/plantillas/style.css');

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([



    ]);

    //Funcion para alterar la plantilla de la factura
    $platilla = getPlantilla($Nombre_Usuario, $Direccion_Usuario, $Email_Usuario, $Factura, $Fecha, $Orden, $Nombre_Metodo, $SubtotalFactura, $CosteEnvio, $productos);

        $mpdf->writeHTML($css, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
    $mpdf->writeHTML($platilla, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);



    $mpdf->Output();

    }
```

CODIGO PARA GUARDAR LOS DATOS:`<?php

```
require_once("conexion.php");

$conexion = new conexion();

if($_POST){

$correo = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "CALL VERIFICAR_USUARIO(:correo, @existe)";

$sentencia = $conexion->conexion->prepare($sql);

$sentencia->bindParam(':correo', $correo, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);

$sentencia->execute();

$sentencia->closeCursor();

$row = $conexion->conexion->query("SELECT @existe as EXISTE")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row['EXISTE'] == "1"){

    $sql = "SELECT ID_USUARIO FROM USUARIO WHERE EMAIL_USUARIO = '$correo'";
    $sentencia = $conexion->consultar($sql);

    $ID_Usuario = $sentencia;

    $lastupdated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $estado = 1;

    $fechaEntrega = NULL;

    $direccion = $_POST['dir'];

    $monto = $_POST['dinero'];

      $sql = "CALL AGREGAR_ORDEN(:ID, :ESTADO, :FECHA, :FECHA_ENTREGA, :DIRECCION, :MONTO,  @ultimo)";

        $sentencia = $conexion->conexion->prepare($sql);

        $sentencia->bindParam(':ID', $ID_Usuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':ESTADO', $estado, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':FECHA', $lastupdated, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':FECHA_ENTREGA', $fechaEntrega, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':DIRECCION', $direccion, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':MONTO', $monto, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $sentencia->execute();

        $sentencia->closeCursor();

        $row = $conexion->conexion->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as LAST")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        IF($row['LAST'] != "0"){

                    try{
                    
                $ID_Orden = $row['LAST'];

                $tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['Tabla']);
                $tableData = json_decode($tableData,TRUE);

                function contarFilas($arreglo){

                $cantidad = 0;

                foreach($arreglo as $elemento){
                 $cantidad ++;
                }

                     return $cantidad;
                }

                $noFilas = contarFilas($tableData);

                for($i = 1; $i < $noFilas; $i++){

                    $ID = $tableData[$i]['ID'];
                    $Precio = $tableData[$i]['Precio'];
                    $Cantidad = $tableData[$i]['Cantidad'];

                    $sql = "CALL AGREGAR_DETALLE(:ORDEN, :PRODUCTO, :PRECIO, :CANTIDAD)";
                    $sentencia = $conexion->conexion->prepare($sql);

                    $sentencia->bindParam(':ORDEN', $ID_Orden, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':PRODUCTO', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':PRECIO', $Precio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':CANTIDAD', $Cantidad, PDO::PARAM_INT);

                    $sentencia->execute();

                    $sentencia->closeCursor();
                }

                    //agregar nueva factura

                    $Fecha_Factura = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
                    $Subtotal = $monto;
                    
                    if($Subtotal > 100){

                        $CosteEnvio = 0;

                    } else {

                        $CosteEnvio = 25;

                    }

                    $Total = $Subtotal + $CosteEnvio;


                    $sql = "CALL NUEVA_FACTURA(:ORDEN, :FECHA, :SUBTOTAL, :COSTENVIO, :MONTO, @ULTIMO)";
                    $sentencia = $conexion->conexion->prepare($sql);

                    $sentencia->bindParam(':ORDEN', $ID_Orden, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':FECHA', $Fecha_Factura, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':SUBTOTAL', $Subtotal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':COSTENVIO', $CosteEnvio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':MONTO', $Total, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                    $sentencia->execute();

                    $sqlOut="SELECT @ULTIMO;";
                    $rs=$conexion->conexion->query($sqlOut);
                    $mData=$rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    //PAGO
                    $ID_Factura = $mData['@ULTIMO'];

                    IF($ID_Factura > '0'){

                    

                    $Metodo = $_POST['pago'];

                    $DPI = NULL;

                    $NombreTarjeta = NULL;

                    $NoTarjeta = NULL;

                    $MesVencimiento = NULL;

                    $AnioVencimiento = NULL;


                    $sql = "CALL SP_PAGO (:FACTURA, :METODO, :DPI, :NOMBRE, :NO, :MES, :ANIO);";
                    $sentencia = $conexion->conexion->prepare($sql);

                    $sentencia->bindParam(':FACTURA', $ID_Factura, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':METODO', $Metodo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':DPI', $DPI, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':NOMBRE', $NombreTarjeta, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':NO', $NoTarjeta, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':MES', $MesVencimiento, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':ANIO', $AnioVencimiento, PDO::PARAM_NULL);

                    $sentencia->execute();


                    }else {
                        
                        echo 'No se pudo generar la factura correctamente';

                    }


                }catch (PDOException  $e){}


        } else{

                    echo 'No se pudo agregar correctamente la orden';


        }

}else{

    echo 'El usuario al que intenta generar una orden no existe.';

}

}
```

?>
`

Comment: Deberias agregar el codigo completo

Comment: Ok, subire el codigo de JS y PHP

Comment: Ya bro, ahi esta

Comment: Intenta declarar las variables fuera del `click`

Comment: Pero ¿por qué dos llamadas a Ajax? Ambos archivos PHP están en contexto de servidor, no necesitas pasar por Ajax dos veces para enlazar ambos archivos, basta con una sola llamada Ajax y ya en el servidor haces un `include` para unir los dos archivos PHP.

Comment: Ya lo probe, me sigue marcando el mismo error.

Comment: Si te soy sincero Cedano, soy muy nuevo en AJAX y JS y no se como funcionan muy bien, por lo que ando probando que hacer. Si quieren les subo imagenes de la GUI para que vean que intento hacer

Comment: Ya estan las imagenes, tal vez con eso se entienda un poco mas lo que estoy intentado realizar.

Comment: Las imágenes sirven de poco en este caso. Explícanos qué debe recogerse en el cliente, para mandarlo al servidor y procesar allí la información. En el servidor, como dije antes, puedes unir uno o más archivos PHP, para lograr el resultado final y devolverlo al cliente si fuera preciso. Estaríamos hablando de una sola petición Ajax en la cual mandas lo que sea y recibes de vuelta la respuesta. Tampoco se entiende mucho de dónde viene el JSON que pones al principio y que tiene una estructura rara: `Usuario` contiene un array y luego propiedades por fuera ¿?

Comment: O dicho de otro modo, aplicándolo a tu contexto: tú puedes guardar los datos, y de inmediato (sin necesidad de volver al cliente) lanzar el código que genera la factura, devolviendo finalmente la factura generada al cliente. No tiene sentido que guardes los datos, vuelvas al cliente a decirle que se guardaron, para que el cliente presione otro botón pidiendo la factura, para volver de nuevo al servidor a generar la factura. Eso sería igual que mandar a vender un producto a Australia, pagas un viaje de regreso para decirte que el producto se vendió, ¿y la factura? pagas oootro viaje ...

Comment: ... para traer la factura. Pero, ¿por qué no trajiste la factura cuando vendiste el producto? Es absurdo volver para buscar la factura. Ajax funciona así son viajes entre el cliente y el servidor. No hagas viajes nuevos si nada ha cambiado en cuanto a los datos. Otra cosa es que el cliente te diga: "es que necesito 10 productos más y además este otro producto". Entonces sí debes hacer otro viaje, porque los datos han cambiado.

Comment: Entonces lo que me recomiendas es que, despues de "pagar" directamente genere la factura? Como hago eso? Realizo un require_once en donde genero la factura o donde trato los datos para incluirlos a la base?

Comment: Te incluyo el codigo de donde se genera la factura para que lo vea

Comment: Ahí esta, agradecería mucho que me pudieras ayudar.

Comment: Sí, una vez guardes los datos (en PHP) puedes pasar a generar la factura haciendo un `require_once` del archivo que genera la factura. Y en Javascript dejas una sola petición Ajax, no dos peticiones Ajax. Inténtalo así y si tienes problemas nos dices, poniendo en la pregunta cómo ha quedado el nuevo código y qué errores tienes. Por cierto, no uses snippets para este caso, porque el código PHP no se puede probar con snippets.

Comment: El require_once de que lado lo hago? Es decir, incluyo la generación de la factura en el archivo que guarda los datos en DB o incluyo el require_once de el guardado a DB en el archivo de generación de factura?

Comment: Debes hacerlo en el orden lógico en que las cosas ocurren. Se supone que lo primero es guardar los datos y una vez guardados, generar la factura. Entonces, en ese mismo orden. En resumen: 1. Guardar los datos en la BD, 2. Verificar que se guardaron bien (puede haber problemas, como clave duplicada u otro) 3. Generar la factura y devolverla al cliente o bien, decir al cliente que hubo algún error (los datos no se pudieron guardar por algún motivo).